# how does html/phtml files works with php files?

Tags: html, zend-framework, php

I am new to web programming and have lot of confusions on some areas. Right now I am working on large web system and need to fix errors. This is on zend framework and front-end html and phtml files on template folder and related php files in controller and model folders. I need to know when you hit a button on front-end how it connects to relevant php file? Php to Php files connects with "include" or "require_once". But how phtml and html template files works with php files?

Answer (score 3):

The way that the Zend MVC framework resolves requests to the different controllers and views is configurable, so a generic answer here may not be super helpful.  Your best bet is to truly understand how the framework works.  Work through the entire Zend Controller QuickStart guide: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.quickstart.html.  It will not take long and will be extremely valuable to you.

The guide will walk you through all the basics and fundamentals of how the MVC framework operates. If you still have questions after working through this thorough guide, then read it again.  Seriously, there is no shortcut answer on SO that will help you more than really understanding what you are working with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...I will read this and see. Thanks again

Comment: Hey I read the whole document twice and I really understand the concept and how its works. This was exactly I was looking for and I was referring this Zend manual couple of times but couldn't find this page. Thank you so much again and I really appreciate your help.